# Method definition error: missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python-3.x, methods

I'm new to coding and I am a terrible noob at Python. I know basic Java, ActionScript, HTML, etc. but this is my first time using Python.

All I need to do is create a variable `i`, assign it a value of a number (let's say 1) and then pass that variable to a method.

The method will be activated on a button click and will modify the `i` variable to a different value.

Here is my code so far:

```
i = 1
print(i)
def record(i)
print("film")
if i == 1:
    i=2
elif i == 2:
    i=1
else:
```

I get the following error:

> record() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'

Answer (score 3):

This is quite simple to fix, you just need to add a `:` at the end of your function and indent the items inside. You also need to add `global` at the beginning of the function to be able to change the variable `i`. Also, don't forget to either add code after the `else` statement at the end, or remove it. For your code it would look something like:

```
i = 1
print(i)
def record(i):
    global i
    print("film")
    if i == 1:
        i=2
    elif i == 2:
        i=1
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that using global variables is not recommended and is a discouraged practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting is a bit off, and it looks like your `else` statement isn't actually doing anything:

```
i = 1
print(i)
def record(i):
  print("film")
  if i == 1:
    i=2
  elif i == 2:
    i=1
```

You're also using the `i` variable as a parameter for the `record` function so any changes to `i` won't be reflected in the `i` on your first line.

In other words, this method isn't really doing anything. Is `i=1` intended to modify `i` outside the class? If so, change the name of your param in `def record(i)` so they don't conflict.

Comment: Its not just "off", its also missing a colon.